# Solving multi-variable integral given known values

Tags: integration

Given the equations:
$$
y = \sum_{n=i_1}^{i_2-1} 2 ^ n 
$$
$$
x = i_2 - i_1
$$ .. How can i solve for x if i know y and i1 in varying situations where I will always know y and $i_1$?  For example, I know that if $y = 24$ and $i_1 = 3$ then $x = 2$.  I'm able to see this since $2^3 = 8$ and $2^4 = 16$ ..  I don't factor in $2^5$ since it's integrated to $i_2 - 1$.

Essentially I'm trying to figure out how many times I need to integrate in order to reach a target of y.  Another example would be that I know $y = 1,000,000$ and $i_1 = 3$ so what would be the value of $x$? ( rounded or accurate would suffice )  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as already answered by pre-kidney, you have $$y=2^{i_2}-2^{i_1}$$ $$x = i_2 - i_1$$ and you knwow the values of $y$ and $i_1$. Ley us rewrite the first as $$2^{i_2}=y+2^{i_1}$$ which gives $$i_2=\frac{\log \left(2^{i_1}+y\right)}{\log (2)}$$ and then $$x=\frac{\log \left(2^{i_1}+y\right)}{\log (2)}-i_1$$ For the example ($y=10^6$,$i_1=3$), this gives $x=16.9316$.

Please note that if $y>>2^{i_1}$, you can have a very good approximation $x \simeq \log_2(y)-i_1$.

Comment: Thank you Claude - Very much appreciate the detail!  Super helpful!  Will put this to good use

Comment: You are welcome !

Answer (score 0):

By geometric series identities, your equation becomes
$$
y=2^{i_2}-2^{i_1}.
$$
Not all $y$ correspond to a solution in terms of $i_1,i_2$.

Comment: Thanks very much pre-kidney!  Really appreciate you pointing out geometric series identities.  Wish I could give both the answer .. Claude helped me a bit further with an equation for x ( which I needed ), so I had to select that as the answer - Sorry / thanks again!